# Ubuntu 16.04: Stop beep when closing/opening laptop lid

Tags: 16.04, sound, laptop, hibernate, mute

I run Ubuntu 16.04 on my old Thinkpad laptop, and I set the laptop to hibernate when when closing the lid. When hibernation occurs an annoying beep is emitted. Likewise when opening the lid, to bring back from hibernation. I succeeded in disabling the beep on one machine but now I need to do it on another and I cannot remember how to change the setting. I think it's via a file under /etc but cannot remember which. Can anyone please advise?

Please note that I have already set the default "alert sound" to "Mute" at All Settings/ Sounds/Sound Effects.

Comment: Is there a beep when starting/restarting/shutting down? Just thinking it's possible that it's a firmware setting.

Comment: When starting I do get a sound, but I replaced the beep there a few years ago with something more pleasant. When restarting (i.e. coming back from hibernation) I get no sound with the laptop that I had successfully "de-beeped" :-) but I get a beep from the one that I still need to "de-beep". When shutting down I cannot recall so I shall have to check that later.

Comment: @wjandrea When the laptop that I already fixed closes down, it does not beep. I shall have to check the other, beep-ing, laptop later.

Comment: Another solution to try: some BIOS settings have the option to disable specific sounds, such as on boot up or low battery. Go into the BIOS and check in there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @PSA and I am sorry to be slow in responding to your suggestion about checking the BIOS settings. As soon as I read your suggestion it stirred a memory of the solution that I had used on the laptop that I had previously fixed. Yes, you were correct! I changed the BIOS setting on the "beeping" laptop and that has fixed the problem. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the files you are looking for are located in the /etc/sound/events directory.
Try opening those files that are related to hibernation and changing the line with `file=XXX.wav` to `file=` (setting it empty) in each file to essentially "mute" the sound (not playing any sound).

Comment: Thanks, but no it's not that. I am working on the laptop that is muted and there are only two entries with .wav, and both are not empty.

Comment: My suggestion was to make the "file" attributes empty.

Comment: Yes, @PSA, thanks, I understand that. What I tried to explain is that the file attributes are exactly the same in the beeping and non-beeping laptops. So the difference must be elsewhere.